# Require a `oneof` in protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want to make a protobuf `Event` message that can contain several different event types. Here's an example:

```
message Event {
    required int32 event_id = 1;

    oneof EventType {
        FooEvent foo_event = 2;
        BarEvent bar_event = 3;
        BazEvent baz_event = 4;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but one thing that bugs me is that `EventType` is optional: I can encode an object with only an `event_id` and protobuf won't complain.

```
>>> e = test_pb2.Event()
>>> e.IsInitialized()
False
>>> e.event_id = 1234
>>> e.IsInitialized()
True
```

Is there any way to require the `EventType` to be set? I'm using Python, if that matters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to Protocol Buffers document, the `required` field rule is not recommended and has already been removed in proto3.

> Required Is Forever You should be very careful about marking fields as required. If at some point you wish to stop writing or sending a required field, it will be problematic to change the field to an optional field – old readers will consider messages without this field to be incomplete and may reject or drop them unintentionally. **You should consider writing application-specific custom validation routines for your buffers instead**. Some engineers at Google have come to the conclusion that using required does more harm than good; they prefer to use only optional and repeated. However, this view is not universal.

And as the above document says, you should consider using application-specific validation instead of marking the fields as `required`.

There is no way to mark a `oneof` as "required" (even in proto2) because at the time `oneof` was introduced, it was already widely accepted that fields probably should never be "required", and so the designers did not bother implementing a way to make a `oneof` required.

Comment: IMO this is a good answer and shouldn't have been downvoted. I added a paragraph tying this back to `oneof` in case that was the reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`options` syntax](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions), there are ways to specify validation rules and auto-generate the code for the validation routines.

You can use https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate like this:

```
import "validate/validate.proto";

message Event {
    required int32 event_id = 1;

    oneof EventType {
        option (validate.required) = true;

        FooEvent foo_event = 2;
        BarEvent bar_event = 3;
        BazEvent baz_event = 4;
    }
}
```

"You should consider writing application-specific custom validation routines for your buffers instead." And here we are auto-generating such custom validation routines.

But wait, is this going against the spirit of protobuf spec? Why is `required` bad and `validate` good? My own answer is that the protobuf spec cares very much about "proxies", i.e. software which serializes/deserializes messages, but has almost no business logic on its own. Such software can simply omit the validation (it's an option), but it cannot omit `required` (it must render the message unparseable).

For business logic's side, all of this is not a big problem in my experience.